# MediaCas object creation failed in Android 11

Tags: android, plugins

Currenty, We are migrating our Android MediaCAS test application to Android-11 from Android-10.

We are running the application in both AVD-29 & AVD-30.

In AVD-29 we didn't observe any issue. While running the same application in AVD-30 we are facing following issue.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: getCurrentUser() from pid=8373, uid=10153 requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS
    
E/MediaCas: Failed to create plugin: java.lang.SecurityException: You either need MANAGE_USERS or CREATE_USERS permission to: query user
```

Sample code:

```
try {
    mMediaCas = new MediaCas(0xF6D8);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("MediacasDebug", "Error" +e);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note: We observed the same behavior in clearkey cas also

Comment: As I checked the AOSP code, there are some changes in MediaCas.java

Answer (score 2):

As per the google this issue will be resolved in future android release

Pls refer: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/179694569